# Programmatically firing a Javascript event on a webpage text field using VB.NET

Tags: javascript, vb.net, dom-events

I'm currently using the built in WebBrowser control in VB.NET to fill out a form on a web page. The form has one required text field in particular that is causing me trouble. The text field is meant to accept a 4 digit year and then perform validation on it to make sure the entered value is in the correct format.

I am able to programmatically enter a year into the text field just fine. However, the form never validates the field afterwards and, therefore, will not allow the form to be submitted. I know the form itself works as I am able to fill it out and submit it manually just fine.

According to the developer tools in Internet Explorer, the only event I see on the field is "change". Normally, I would use the line below to fire the "change" event in VB.NET, however I instead get an exception indicating the change event does not exist:

`fMain.w1.Document.GetElementById("Sections[0].Year").RaiseEvent("change")`

The code for the text field itself is below.

```
<input name="Sections[0].Year" tabindex="1" title="Year" class="required number digits numbers-only bind-x" style="width: 50px;" type="text" value="1924" data-metadata="{'validate':{'required':true,'number':true,'dynamic':['range',$abc.building_edit.yearRange],'digits':true,'messages':{'dynamic':$.validator.messages.range}}}" data-sectionnum="1" value="1924"></input>
```

I'm not that familiar with Javascript so I don't know if I'm even looking in the right place or if I'm providing enough information for you to help, but any information you can give to at least get me on the right track would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with [`onchange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event name:

```
fMain.w1.Document.GetElementById("Sections[0].Year").RaiseEvent("onchange")
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, I tried "onchange" but the text field still did not go through validation or allow the form to be submitted. However, I also did not receive an exception this time.

Comment: Don't fire the javascript. Just find out what is being set by the piece of code and set that manually.